# Php foreach replace values inside array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops, replace

I try to create a Helper function which shall replace the short names of language to their full names.

I have a constants file which looks like this (using laravel that is why the constant looks like this):

```
<?php

return [
    'languages' => [
        'names' => [
            'Bulgarian' => 'bg',
            'Danish' => 'da',
            'German' => 'de',
            'English' => 'en'
            ...
        ],
    ]
];
```

My function so far looks like this:

```
public static function replaceName($string = '')
{
    $langName = Config::get('constants.languages.names');
    foreach($langName as $langKey => $langValue)
    {
        $search  = array($langValue);
        $replace = array($langKey);
    }
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}
```

But it still does not work any ideas?

Comment: You want to replace 'German' with 'de'? Then do `return str_replace(array_keys( $langName),  $langName, $string);` else `return str_replace($langName,array_keys( $langName), $string);`

Comment: No I want to replace de with German

Comment: Did you now how many word have the `de` part in it?

Comment: in my case there can only be one do not worry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) as:

```
array_search('de', Config::get('constants.languages.names')) // returns German
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

> Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful.

Answer (score 0):

One way to rome.

```
public static function replaceName($string = '')
{
  $langName = Config::get('constants.languages.names');
  foreach($langName as $langKey => $langValue)
  {
    $search[]  = " $langValue ";
    $replace[] = " $langKey ";
  }
  return str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}
```

It replaces only full words with spaces before and after it!

We dont want to `Ben` become `BEnglish`! ;) If this is not needed, remove the spaces.

##############################################

When `$string` only has `de` as content, then:

```
public static function replaceName($string = '')
{
  $langName = array_flip(Config::get('constants.languages.names'));
  return isset($langName[$string])?$langName[$string]:$string;
}
```